# android button release pressed

Tags: android, button, contextmenu, pressed

[See problem in photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOHYQ.jpg)

I am using selector and Touch listener to set button pressed on MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN in fragment. But when Context Menu is called button become not pressed.This onTouch method inside fragment:

```
 @Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.buttonRow:
                if (!buttonRow.isPressed()) {
                    buttonRow.setPressed(true);
                    buttonGrid.setPressed(false);
                    setLinearManager();
                }
                break;
            case R.id.buttonGrid:
                if (!buttonGrid.isPressed()) {
                    buttonGrid.setPressed(true);
                    buttonRow.setPressed(false);
                    setGridManager();
                }
                break;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Fragment xml where buttons located:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.boss.lesson5.fragments.RecyclerViewFragment">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/buttonRow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@drawable/button_effect"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/row" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/buttonGrid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@drawable/button_effect"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/grid" />
</LinearLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp" />
```

Answer (score 1):

try working with this model :

```
myBtn.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){

                   //do stuff
                }
                else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                    //do stuff
                }
                else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL){
                    //do stuff
                }
            return true;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Didn't helped, MotionEvent didn't call when I click context menu.